# Resultado em um Dataframe com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import psutil as ps

names = []

for service in ps.win_service_iter():

    info = service.as_dict()
    listOf =  [("Name:%s; " "Display_Name:%s; " "Status:%s " % (info['name'],info['display_name'],info['status']))]

    names.append(listOf)

names
```

E preciso que o resultado desse for seja dentro de um DF com as seguintes colunas: Nome, Nome_Display, Status.

Podem me ajudar?

---

**Fiz esse script também, onde coloca o resultado em DF, porém, fica inutilizável filtros ou LOC, acredito que pelo fato de como traz o resultado:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import psutil as ps

names = []
display = []
status = []

for service in ps.win_service_iter():

    info = service.as_dict()
    listOfNames =  [("%s" % (info['name']))]
    listOfDisplay   =  [("%s" % (info['display_name']))]
    listOfStatus  =  [("%s" % (info['status']))]

    names.append(listOfNames)
    display.append(listOfDisplay)
    status.append(listOfStatus)

zippedList =  list(zip(names, display, status))

df = pd.DataFrame(zippedList, columns = ['Name' , 'Display', 'Status']) 

df
```

Comment: Sua pergunta esta confusa amigo, consegue explicar melhor?

Comment: Preciso colocar o resultado desse for em um dataframe.. o script me retorna assim:
['Name:AJRouter; Display_Name:AllJoyn Router Service; Status:stopped '],
 ['Name:ALG; Display_Name:Application Layer Gateway Service; Status:stopped '],.

Comment: Porem, quando zip a lista -- zippedList =  list(zip(names)), coloco em um DataFrame -- df = pd.DataFrame(zippedList, columns = ['Name' , 'Display', 'Status'])  ela não fica utilizável por exemplo com LOC, não busca os registros?

Comment: O que significa `resultado do for`? O constructo de linguagem `for` é um laço de iteração sobre um dado e um bloco de ações, essas ações podem ou não modificar ou criar dados, mas não retorna dados. O constructo de linguagem usado para retornar informação é a função, método ou propriedade. Caso surja a pergunta, a variável armazena o dado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poderá fazer assim:

```
#import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import psutil as ps

names = []
for service in ps.win_service_iter():
    info = service.as_dict()
    names.append({
        'nome': info['name'],
        'nome_display': info['display_name'],
        'status': info['status']

    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=names)
df
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Solução perfeita, obrigado!